How can I resolve a "ConnectionRefusedError" in Python, specifically the error "[WinError 10061] No connection could be made
When attempting to send an email using a Flask application designed to generate tokens for users to recover their passwords, I encountered an issue. Specifically, I received a "ConnectionRefusedError" with the message "[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it". How can I resolve this error and successfully send emails from my Flask app for password recovery purposes?
I attempted to send an email from my Flask application to generate tokens for users to recover their passwords. However, I encountered a "ConnectionRefusedError" with the message "[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it". I expected the email to be sent successfully without any errors.

This could mean a number of things:
A) To whatever ip address and port you sent a request is blocked.
B) The ip address/ port does not exist.
C) The port is full.
Also you should check out this question concerning flask:
Can't connect to Flask web service, connection refused
You should check if it is your firewall.
